# How do I make the vertical lines in a LyX table match the size of the table?

Tags: tables, lyx

I created a table in LyX, and then right-clicked the table, clicked: Settings -> Borders, then put "2mm" for the additional space at the top of the row.

The LaTeX code generated by LyX is the following:

```
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline 
\noalign{\vskip2mm}
a & b & c & d & e & f\tabularnewline[2mm]
\hline 
\end{tabular}
```

This is what the PDF looks like:

[image]

I do not like the huge gap in the vertical lines!!

I searched all over the net to see if someone else asked the same question.
Here's a similar problem but for horizontal lines: [Horizontal lines don't close in table using LyX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/466396/horizontal-lines-dont-close-in-table-using-lyx) (but the answer was to change the table width in LyX, which doesn't seem to be an option for vertical lines).

This question: [Lyx Table Vertical Alignment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/439742/lyx-table-vertical-alignment), seems to be related, but upon closer look it doesn't solve the specific problem I have.

Is there a way to solve this problem in LyX, without first making the table in TeX and then bringing it into the LyX editor?

Comment: 4 days, no up or down votes, no answers, no comments, no close votes, only 8 views!

Comment: Well, to earn badge "invisible", you should wait 26 days more :-). With this comment this opportunity is now lost ... Your approach to design of table is wrong. One of possibilities is: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makecell}
\begin{document}
{
\setcellgapes{5mm}% here set desired vertical space
\makegapedcells
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
a & b & c & d & e & f\tabularnewline
\hline
\end{tabular}
}
\end{document}`. Since I'm not familiar with LyX, I don't know, how to adopt this solution to it.

Comment: So the only difference is the "setcellpages" and "makegapedcells" ?

Comment: which are defined in the package `makecell`. Do you expect some more spectacular solution?

Comment: @Zarko, I am just looking for something I can do in LyX! It does not need to be spectacular at all!

Comment: My suggestion should work in LyX too. You need only add proposed code to it (on the way as LyX require.